# import rpy2.ipython meet error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'

Tags: python-3.x

My python version is 3.6. my OS is windows. After install rpy2 module, when I type  import rpy2, got no issue. But when type import rpy2.ipython, got error as below:

```
>>> import rpy2.ipython

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\Soft_app\Python\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py", line 76
    "either.")))
UserWarning: The Python package 'pandas' is strongly recommended when using `rpy2.ipython`. Unfortunately it could not be loaded, and we did not manage to load 'numpy' either.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import rpy2.ipython
  File "D:\Soft_app\Python\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .rmagic import load_ipython_extension
  File "D:\Soft_app\Python\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py", line 81, in <module>
    from IPython.core.displaypub import publish_display_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'
```

Can help to figure out what's issue??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing Ipython and pandas. Installing them should resolve your issue.

Run "pip install ipython" to install Ipython and run "pip install pandas" to install pandas.

Hopefully, this will solve your problem.

Happy Coding ~